# How to set Firefox Profile: Selenium RC, .Net Client Driver?

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, client, driver

I'm using Selenium RC + .Net Client Driver. I've created a Firefox profile in my c:\selenium\ directory. Here's my code:

```
Dim MySelenium As ISelenium = Nothing
MySelenium = New DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*custom C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe  -profile c:/selenium/", "http://www.google.com/")
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to launch it via RC rather than in your code.

So you would do

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate c:\selenium\
```

to launch the browser and then do

```
Dim MySelenium As ISelenium = Nothing
MySelenium = New DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com/")
```

and that should launch Firefox for with the profile you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can create the Selenium Server programmatically and pass a File as the newFirefoxProfileTemplate configuration property:

```
RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
rcc.setPort(5499);
rcc.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(newFirefoxProfileTemplate); // This is a File object
SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(rcc);

server.start();
```

Perhaps there are similar (or the same) vb.net classes available.