# Using a specific Firefox profile in Selenium WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use a profile I already have set up for firefox with selenium 2 but there is no documentation for C#.  The code I have attempted is as follows:

```
FirefoxProfileManager profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile(profileName);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Code that I have seen that is comparible in Java uses ProfilesIni instead of FirefoxProfileManager, but that is not available in C#.  When setting up the driver in this way the selenium profile used has all the default settings instead of the settings specified in the profile I am trying to point to.

I am not sure that I am using the correct methods to retrieve the profile, but if anyone has used Selenium 2 with C#, any information would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250486/how-to-set-firefox-profile-selenium-rc-net-client-driver

Comment: This is not a duplicate thread, the other thread refers to Selenium RC and unabel to start the brower.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

We use such method to load default firefox profile (you can create custom profile and load it):

```
private IWebDriver driver;  
string pathToCurrentUserProfiles = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%APPDATA%") + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"; // Path to profile
string[] pathsToProfiles = Directory.GetDirectories(pathToCurrentUserProfiles, "*.default", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if (pathsToProfiles.Length != 0)
{
     FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(pathsToProfiles[0]);
     profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.loadInBackground", false); // set preferences you need
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), profile, serverTimeout);
}
else
{
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

Comment: which version of Selenium ? For 2.23.0 nothing works not even this.

Comment: Totally makes sense. Pasiba for response.

Comment: This code worked for me with some minor tweaks.  Thanks

Comment: `string pathToCurrentUserProfiles = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"Comodo\IceDragon\Profiles"); `

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem that the profile wouldn't load. The problem is in FirefoxProfile (line 137). It only looks for user.js and the profile from Firefox is actually prefs.js

137>>    File prefsInModel = new File(model, "user.js");

Hack solution: rename prefs.js --> user.js

Comment: Worked for me, just need to make sure that you are in the actual profile folder, don't zip the folder itself

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.  I had to specifically set the "webdriver.firefox.profile" preference in order to get it to work.

```
        var allProfiles = new FirefoxProfileManager();

        if (!allProfiles.ExistingProfiles.Contains("SeleniumUser"))
        {
            throw new Exception("SeleniumUser firefox profile does not exist, please create it first.");
        }
        var profile = allProfiles.GetProfile("SeleniumUser");

        profile.SetPreference("webdriver.firefox.profile", "SeleniumUser");

        WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

After using the aforementioned answers I had no result, so I tried the following alternate way:

First, create the desired profile by typing about:profiles on Firefox address bar.

Second, the C# code. Note that the profile name we created on first step is passed as an argument.

```cs
public IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
    
public Selenium(String nombrePefil)
{
    if (this.driver == null)
    {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();                     

        options.AddArgument("--profile " + nombrePefil);

        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);                        
                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it is not a duplicate.

I am using the following which works

```
private IWebDriver Driver;

[Setup]
public void SetupTest()
{
string path = @"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\myi5go1k.default";
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
}
```

Comment: Even when I create a profile in the default location Selenium webdriver still insists on using a new profile.  I know the path is right the webdriver just refuses to use it.  The profile is great I can lanch firefox using the profile via the profile manager.  Stumped!!

Comment: Out of desperation I've update Selenium, that didn't work so I updated FireFox, still no joy.  Anyone know if you can do anything with the SetPreference method?

Comment: Same problem... even with `profile.SetPreference("webdriver.firefox.profile", "SeleniumUser");` it doesn't use any history or saved passwords of SeleniumUser

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered the same issue, and after searching and trying many different combinations I was able to get Selenium to load a specific profile when using the RemoteWebDriver.

**Grid configuration**

I launch the HUB using a batch file containing the following

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\Downloads\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -maxSession 50 -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=Selenium
```

I launch one or more nodes using a batch file containing the following (each node has a unique port number):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS,version=11.0,maxInstances=2 -maxSession 2 -port 5555 -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=Selenium
```

The key here is the last part of those commands, which needs to match the name of the custom profile you have created.

**Code to create WebDriver instance**

```
private readonly Uri _remoteWebDriverDefaultUri = new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/");

private IWebDriver CreateFireFoxWebDriver(Uri remoteWebDriverUri)
{
    var desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "11.0");

    var drv = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteWebDriverUri ?? _remoteWebDriverDefaultUri, desiredCapabilities);

    return drv;
}
```

**NOTE:** The capabilities need to match those of the nodes you are running in the grid.

You can then call this method passing in the Uri of the hub, or null to default to localhost.

Answer (score -1):

Seems fine with the Roaming profile rather than the local profile.

string path = @"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\myi5go1k.default";
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);