# How can I call a bookmarklet from Selenium webdriver? (Visual Studio, C#)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium, imacros

The FirefoxDriver instance opened by Seleniums Webdriver does not have a bookmarks menu and does not respond to the hotkeys assigned to imacros.

Is there a way to include bookmarks in a FirefoxDriver instance?

Or a way to call imacros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to create a separate firefox profile which has the bookmarks/hotkeys enabled (it sounds like they are enabled on your default profile) and then set your test to use that profile. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680516/2386700

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue